# Uniform continuity is simply not enough for the proof...

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

It seeems that the following statement is just a consequence of the uniform continuity of $F$, but I found that it is not that trivial to prove:

Suppose that $F:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow X$ is a continuous map. Let $\gamma_{u}(t)=F(t,u)$ and assume that $\gamma_{0}([0,1])\subseteq G$ for some open set $G$, then there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\gamma_{u}(t)\in G$ for all $u\in[0,1]$ with $|u|<\delta$ and $t\in[0,1]$.

I think the fact that continuity implies uniform continuity is not sufficient for looking the required $\delta>0$, maybe we need some sort of Lebesgue number of covering as well?

Comment: What is $X$? An arbitrary topological space?  A metric space?

Comment: An arbitrary topological space. But in pratice I just need it to be an $n$-dimensional (real) manifold, or we can try for the case that $X$ to be the complex plane.

Comment: For every $t \in [0,1]$, choose $\delta_t$ such that if $\max(|t'-t|,|u|) < \delta_t$, $F(t',u) \in G$. The sets $(t - \delta_t, t + \delta t)$ cover $[0,1]$, so...

Comment: $F^{-1}(G)$ is open and contains the slice  $0\times [0,1]$ so the result follows by the tube lemma.

Comment: Surprisingly by means of the tube lemma the uniform continuity plays no role in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that no such $\delta$ exists.

Then, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists a $t_n\in[0,1]$, such that
$$
\gamma_{1/n}(t_n)\in X\setminus G.
$$
Clearly, $\{t_n\}$ possesses a convergent subsequence, $\{t_{n_k}\}$, with $t_{n_k}\to s \in[0,1]$, and 
$$
\gamma_{1/n_k}(t_{n_k})\in X\setminus G.
$$

If we further assume that $X$ is a manifold, and hence metrisable, then continuity of $F$ implies that
$$
\gamma_{1/n_k}(t_{n_k})=F(t_{n_k},1/n_k)\to F(s,0)=\gamma_0(s)\in X\setminus G,
$$
since $X\setminus G$ is closed.

Contradiction.